# RESTful routes for Cakephp Plugin

Tags: php, rest, cakephp

I am facing some problems to configure Restful routes to custom plugin in my cakephp application. Routes are not be directed to appropriate action on the basis of type of rest operation performed.

Code in routes.php

```
Router::resourceMap( array(
    array( 'action' => 'index', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => false ),
    array( 'action' => 'view', 'method' => 'GET', 'id' => true ),
    array( 'action' => 'add', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => false),
    array( 'action' => 'edit', 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => true ),
    array( 'action' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => true ),
) );
Router::mapResources('chronos.chronosApplications'); // chronos is plugin name and chronosApplications is controller in this plugin
```

Request url i am using is /chronos/chronosApplications/1 with request type delete.

Error logs are

```
2015-10-20 16:14:23 Error: [MissingActionException] Action ChronosApplicationsController::40() could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'ChronosApplicationsController',
  'action' => '40',
)
Request URL: /chronos/chronosApplications/40
Stack Trace:
#0 /usr/share/pear/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(185): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#1 /usr/share/pear/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(160): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(ChronosApplicationsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#2 /var/www/prime/desman/webroot/index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#3 {main}
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

First of all its "mapResources", but to define routes you use "Router::connect('link', 'action', 'obs');".

Read more about it in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes

Comment: i am trying to implement restful routes . if i define using Router::connect then they are going to be static kind of .